# StackOverflowError inserting data into Perst database

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow

I have a long-running process which consumes data from multiple clients and stores that data into a Perst database.   The Perst database is embedded and stores the data to the disk.   However, after several hours, a StackOverflowError is thrown when inserting data into the database.

It appears as though Perst uses its own memory store to contain recently inserted data.   From my understanding, this memory store is broken up into chunks and when Perst wants to store some data, it looks for enough of these chunks into which it can place the data.

Each lookup seems to find adjacent chunks, but if it can't find enough adjacent chunks for the data it wants to store, then it recurses and looks for an additional block of chunks which it can use.   So the more fragmented the memory store becomes, the more recursion is required, eventually leading to a StackOverflowError, or at least that's my current hypothesis.

Here's the repeating section from the stack trace:

```
at org.garret.perst.impl.StorageImpl.cloneBitmap(StorageImpl.java:773)
at org.garret.perst.impl.StorageImpl.putPage(StorageImpl.java:107)
at org.garret.perst.impl.StorageImpl.putBitmapPage(StorageImpl.java:340)
at org.garret.perst.impl.StorageImpl.allocate(StorageImpl.java:417)
```

My questions are:

- is this understanding correct?
- what can be done to prevent this?

Note:

I'm using a rather old version of Perst (2.6.4) and looking at the changelog, a recursion problem has since been fixed, which looks very similar to what I'm experiencing - but upgrading Perst would be a big task, ideally I'm looking for a more simple fix or a configuration change which would help.